# Inserting or updating an attribute of an object within an array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor

I am attempting to update (or insert) an attribute of an object within an array in MongoDB, but I don't seem to be able to access the array (apps), or the attribute (appId).

Basically, what's happening is the array of "apps" is being created, but the appId is not populating as it should be.

Can anyone take a look and provide some insight?

```
Template.CurriculumBuilder.events({
   'submit #addToCurriculum': function(e) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const appId = this._id;
    console.log('Here is the app id --> ' + appId)

    const userId = Meteor.user()._id;
    console.log('Here is the user id --> ' + userId);

    const doc = Curriculum.findOne({ user: userId });
    console.log('Here is the doc id --> ' + doc._id)

    Curriculum.update(doc._id, { $set: { apps: [{ $addToSet: { appId: appId } } ] } } );
    console.log('Apps have been added to --> ' + doc._id)

    return false;
}
});
```

***UPDATE***

As answered below, the DB call should be:

```
Curriculum.update(doc._id,{ $addToSet: { apps: { appId: appId } } } );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `$set` or the square brackets:

```
Curriculum.update(doc._id,{ $addToSet: { apps: { appId: appId } } );
```

In English:

> add the object `{appId: appId}` to the array `apps` in the document whose `_id` is `doc._id`

Comment: Sure. I think I just did. One another quick question. Would inserting data into a new Curriculum work similarly? So, Curriculum.insert({ $addToSet: { apps: { appId: appId } } ); ?

Comment: I think you'd want `Curriculum.insert({ apps: [{ appId: appId }] } );` to initialize.

Comment: What if, I have a separate Array called "userAppList" ... with multiple ID's, already created BEFORE I want to "Insert" or create the document?

Comment: Then you can just do:  `Curriculum.insert({ apps: userAppList } )`